# Internal storage folders and files

Tags: android, internal-storage

I have folder with assets. and i need to copy all media to

> data/data/packagename/

and create there 5 folders for sounds imgs, videos. How can I do it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following,

```
 File path=getFilesDir();
 String mypath=path.toString() + "/myfolder";
 OutputStreamWriter out;
 try {
        File  f = new File(mypath , "/myfile.txt"   );
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(f.getPath(),MODE_PRIVATE));
        out.write("test");
        out.close();                   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following permission in your app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```